# Implement pagination in treeView of angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How to implement pagination in treeview of ui-grid, where the page should consider only the header as a single line. Currently my $scope.gridoptions.data will have both header and sub-lines in same array. 
On click of expand it should expand and still consider only the header for number of lines in page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you add a screenshot may be?

Comment: Something like the one which is there in ui-grid demo for tree view  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_treeView. Here also all the data are pushed to gridOptionsdata as normal row only irrespective of header or line. But in my scenario, I need to do pagination only with respect to header and not lines. Thank you